# How to identify the resource bound of the system

Tags: io, resources

I want to test the performance of the databases above different storages (i.e., SSD-1, SSD-2, HDD-1, HDD-2...). To expose the difference in performance above different storages, I want to make the database workload disk-I/O-intensive (using write-intensive workload).

**But** how to confirm that the system is bounded by disk I/O rather than something else like CPU, memory accesses, etc. Does simply using `top` to see the CPU usage (`Usage-in-percent`/`CPU-cores` < 100%) works?

For example, I run

```
sysbench fileio --file-num=16 --file-total-size=2G --file-fsync-all=on --file-test-mode=seqwr --time=30 run
```

and monitor with `top`:

```sh
PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP
33998  sysbench     54.8 00:03.29 2/1   0    11    1316K  0B     0B     3399
```

Does this mean the system is bounded by disk-IO?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit vague. Are you asking about a way to identify the bottleneck of a generic system, or just a particular database, or disk performance of a different drives??

I would say its possible to design a benchmark that stresses disk more than other things, but probably not possible to propose a general algorithm to identify system bottleneck.

the way you design/engineer a particular benchmark against a particular application usually involves at least some high level familiarity of what the application is doing and then reason why a particular benchmark stresses resource A and not resource B. you might need to do other control benchmarks to conclude resource B is really not bottlenecked and nothing else is also ... like all things engineering, iteration is your friend.

If you are trying to get an idea on say "how much does this particular SSD improve the performance of my postgres database??" that really depends on the application workload. the answer maybe none at all or quite a lot.

what i can tell you is that the sysbench fileio benchmark will say nothing about that question.

conversely the sysbench OLTP benchmark probably tells you not much about a "disk constraint database workload" because i think it would do too much table locking and lock contention in general for it to be disk constrained.

For example some recent benchmarking I was doing I found pg13 to be capable of doing nearly 400k (yes nearly half a million) 100 byte record insertions per second, on a old 8 core gaming pc with consumer SSD which was quite a bit more than the 1000 transactions per second reported by sysbench OLTP benchmark